# blocking ultrasonic frequencies

Tags: studio-design, high-frequency

Hey All,

There's this ultrasonic motion detector in my room that the studio installed. Which is great at turning off my lights if I forget to and also great at ruining any chance of pitching the recordings I do in the room. It's blazing at about 30+khz so when I slow down anything I record in here the cue is useless(devoured by 15k frequencies). The unit hardwired into the ceiling so I can't turn it off and I tried putting a moving blanket of the the device but that doesn't seem block any of the high frequencies. Any ideas? Can any type of sound proofing fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having it replaced with an infrared motion detector?

Otherwise, high frequencies can be reflected with dense material, so if you have a closed wooden box (mdf is very dense) that you can put up around the detector, the sound will stay trapped inside and bounce around without coming out. Having some kind of rubber seal between the box and the ceiling will improve the shielding.

Comment: Thanks! I can't replace the device because it's the studio's room so, I'll try securing a metal bowl over it. 

Comment: @EMV I stuck a pie tin up on the ceiling, it seemed to lower the noise by about 20db. Gonna puta rubber seal on there next. See if I can completely eliminate the sound.

Comment: @Jake Cool, nice to hear you're getting results!

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the light permanently and bringing in your own lights.  Before our last refit we had fluorescent tubes that whined when on, so I just never turned them on.  If you are lucky the motion detector is switched off when the lights are off.